# How to activate the Elite Soldier Pack for XCOM PC Version

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I honestly tried all common sense approaches to activating the Elite Soldier Pack for my PC DVD version of XCOM - Enemy Unknown and have not managed to do it. The leaflet that comes in the box says that once I install the game, I should "redeem my Soldier Pack with the following code" (I'm guessing on Steam Service), but I've found no such option on Steam, if I click the DLC button on Steam it says there's no DLC for this game, and also trying the "redeem" option in the upper menu of the Steam client and entering the code on the Elite Soldier leaflet didn't work (says code is invalid).

So please, if anyone has bought the PC DVD version and than has managed to activate his Elite Soldier Pack, can you please tell me how you did it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redeem that code just like you'd do for full-game CD-key.

> Please follow these instructions to activate a new retail purchase on
>   Steam:
>
> 1. Launch Steam and log into your Steam account.
> 2. Click the **Games Menu**.
> 3. Choose **Activate a Product on Steam**...
>
> Follow the onscreen instructions to complete the process.

This will activate the DLC. That worked for me. If it doesn't, you should contact the support.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Just wants to download the game again. Doesn't seem to know I have a version that is supposed to come with DLC pack.

Comment: @Berserk Are you sure it's trying to download the whole game again and not just the DLC content?